# CSVPrinter print delimiter before each line

Tags: java, spring, export-to-csv, apache-commons

I need to write a csv with java, I'm using org.apache.commons, but when printing the file the delimiter ";" appears before each line.

My code

```
public static Object createCsvFile(JsonArray array, HttpServletResponse response) {
    var header = array.get(0).getAsJsonObject().keySet();

    try {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(stringWriter, CSVFormat.newFormat(';'));
        csvPrinter.printRecord(header);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject values = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
            csvPrinter.print("\r\n");
            for (String key: keys) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(values.get(key).toString() + ";");
            }
        }
        csvPrinter.close();
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

My result

```
;4;"11/10/2022 06:10";117;"ENTRADA POR PRODUCAO";422;"LINGUICA DE CARNE SUINA - AURORA - 5KG - CHURRASCO";"MI";"078911644790352718";"0422101011";"10/10/2022";1025;"116-BRASIL - MI";
```

Note that before the 4 there is a ";"

I tried to use some alternatives that I found in the user guide, but I didn't get anything.

Comment: That would mean the first field is empty

Comment: This looks dubious in that position: *csvPrinter.print("\r\n");* Also, I don't see the response being used at all. I don't know that api but this also looks dubious:       *csvPrinter.printRecord(values.get(key).toString() + ";");* Why would you add delimiters explicitly when you've given the format?

Comment: Don't mix and match `print/println` and `printRecord`.  Also, you don't pass a String into printRecord, you pass in an array/Iterable that gets processed with `toString()`

Comment: @g00se my first field 4, there is no other before it;

I passed ";" explicitly, because he didn't place it automatically, so it was as accurate.

the only thing is that he is putting a ";" unnecessary predecessor.

Comment: @kendavidson I'm getting this value from a json array, so I passed it this way. Do you recommend passing this jsonarray to a list or array and then inserting it into the txt?

Comment: As it is right now you're creating a `newFormat` (; delimiter but null record separator) so that's probably why you are adding the manual `\r\n`.  You probably want to use one of the preconfigured formats `CSVFormat.EXCEL.setDelimiter(';')` then use only `printRecord(keys)`.

Comment: @kendavidson keys, have the header values. The values I need are inside the key, so I need "values.get(key).toString()". See how it goes doing as you recommended:
https://ibb.co/8bM3yFm

I tried to adjust it to how I had done it and I couldn't, because as "values.get(key).toString()" is an array, it creates a line for each value, see https://ibb.co/2YKDps7

Do you have any idea how I can print this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `+ ";"` in `csvPrinter.printRecord(values.get(key).toString() + ";");`, you'll see that it's your `CSVPrinter` that add them before each line.

You should let your `CSVPrinter` handle the delimiter.

Just to give you some inspiration, try with this :

```java
public static Object createCsvFileBis(JsonArray array, HttpServletResponse response) {
    var header = array.get(0).getAsJsonObject().keySet();

    try (
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(stringWriter, CSVFormat.newFormat(';'))
    ) {
        csvPrinter.printRecord(header);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject values = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
            csvPrinter.printRecord("\n");
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String key : keys) {
                row.add(values.get(key).toString());
            }
            csvPrinter.printRecord(row);
        }
        csvPrinter.flush();
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, follow your example and I got it, I just changed the way to create the header, doing it as follows.

` for (String head : header) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(head);
            }`